# Solr Stopwords Removal Cases

Tags: solr, stop-words

Is there any Solr configuration that when the search term is just a stop-word, it does not treat it as stop-word and finds the relevant docs.
e.g.

- if query is **alpha and beta**,it is treated as *alpha beta*
- if query is **and**, it is treated as *and*(as the query contains
  only stop-word/s)

For the time being I am not considering exact phrase match.

Comment: remove the stopwordfilterfactory from your fieldType...while indexing and quering...

Comment: in that case in alpha and beta , solr will search "and" as separate token. and I dont want that, as I get many results because of individual stopwords.

Comment: then use the string as the filedType so it consider a single token

Answer (score 4):

Use two fields - one with stop words removed, and one with all tokens preserved. This will allow you to give the different hits different weights (meaning that hits in the field which *has* the stop words present can be weighted lower than hits where the stop words has been removed).

You can do this by having two different field definitions (`text_with_stopwords` and `text_without_stopwords`) with different analyzer chains.

Query and weight the fields differently by using `qf=text_wosw^2 text_wsw`, and index the same content into both fields by using a `copyField` directive.

Solr has no way of doing "if no hits in this field, search in this field" by itself, so if you want the searches to be performed separately, you'll have to handle that in your application (if the first query in the field without stop words doesn't give any hits, make a query against the other field).